# Regex for set of Hashtags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for validating one or more hashtags. Each hashtag ends with comma or space.

These are the valid inputs:

`#hashtagTest`

`#hashtagTest1, #hashtagTest2`

`#hashtagTest1,#hashtagTest2`

I've been trying to do this in javascript but with no success so far.

These are invalid inputs:

`#hashtagTest hashtagTest`,
`#r #m`

`#hashtagTest#hashtagTest`

Comment: @Lucero I have tried this `/^[#]+[a-z0-9]*[, ]$/` but it is working only for single hashtag with comma ("#hashtagTest,")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work

```
/(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+,? *)*#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

See the explanation and test it here https://regex101.com/r/0NJkgq/2

You might want to add begin and end of line markers to make sure the whole string is a sequence of tags

```
/^(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+,? *)*#[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

If you want to find all the occurrences of sequences of tags in a string you can use

```
/(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+,? *)*#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g
```

The `g` modifiers allows to find all the occurrences of the regexp in a string

Comment: `/(#[a-zA-Z0-9]+,? *)*#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g` this expression is working for all my inputs except `#hashtag1#hashtag2`. It should not allow two hashtags in same word. Hashtags should be seperated by comma or space

Comment: If you just want to get the tags, not validating that they are separated by space or coma, simply use  /#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g https://regex101.com/r/zOFtcG/1

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have added invalid inputs to description also. Please check once

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = prompt("String: ");

var match = str.match(/#[a-z\d][a-z-]*/gi);

if(match)
  console.log(match);
else
  console.log("Nothing matched!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /#\w+/gm;
const str = `#hashtagTest

#hashtagTest1, #hashtagTest2

#hashtagTest1,#hashtagTest2`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work for you.

```
/#[a-z][\w]*/gi
```